# PHP matrix function

Tags: php, matrix

i did function which will print matrix, add, multiply etc but how can i change it to work with not only square matrix, for example 3x4? i have no idea. Is it possible to edit this code or i need something completly diffrent?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>


<?php
echo '<pre>';
$matrix = array (
  array(5,2,11),
  array(2,4,5),
  array(21,7,9),
);

$matrix1 = array (
  array(84,91,23),
  array(55,2,13),
  array(41,66,11),
);

// zadanie 1

echo var_dump($matrix);
echo '<br>';
echo print_r($matrix);

echo '<br>';
function print_matrix($matrix) {

$n = count($matrix);
for ($i = 0; $i < $n; ++$i) {


for ($j = 0; $j < $n; ++$j) {

 print_r($matrix[$i][$j]);
echo ' ';
if ($j == $n - 1)
 echo PHP_EOL;
        }
    }

}

echo print_matrix($matrix);
echo '<br>';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$matrix = array ( // 3x4
    array(5,2,11, 2),
    array(2,4,5, 2),
    array(21,7,9, 2),
);

function print_matrix($matrix) {
    foreach ($matrix as $key => $value) {
        foreach ($value as $key1 => $value1) {
            echo ' '.$value1;
        }
        echo '<br/>';
    }
}
```

or

```
function print_matrix2($matrix) {

    $countColumns = count($matrix);
    for ($key = 0; $key < $countColumns; $key++) {


        $countLine = count($matrix[$key]);
        for ($key2 = 0; $key2 < $countLine; $key2++) {

            print_r($matrix[$key][$key2]);
            echo ' ';

        }
        echo '<br/>';
    }

}
```

Comment: **Good answers** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way,
not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO that may find this question and be reading your answer. If it is well answered maybe they will UpVote it.